# zend validator premature message

Tags: zend-framework

I'm finding that the Zend "required" validator is generating tips in my forms earlier than I want it to.  When a form is first rendered in the browser, before the user has submitted anything, it displays "value is required and can't be empty."  I'd like that to only show up *after* something is submitted that fails the validation check.  Is there a Zend-standard way to do this, or do I need to write something that will make this stateful the way I want it?

I'm new so I think this is pretty basic stuff:

Here's the form:

```
class Application_Form_Login extends Zend_Form
{


    public function init()
    {
        /* Form Elements & Other Definitions Here ... */
        $this->setMethod('post');

        $this->addElement(
            'text', 'username', array(
                'label' => 'Username:',
                'required' => true,
                'filters' => array('StringTrim'),       
            )
        );

        $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array(
            'ignore' => true,
            'label' => 'Login', 
        ));
    }
}
```

And it's displayed with this code:

```
public function indexAction()
{
    // action body
    $db = $this->_getParam('db');
    $loginForm = new Application_Form_Login();

    if($loginForm->isValid($_POST)) {
        $adapter = new Zend_Auth_Adapter_DbTable(
            $db,
            'users',
            'username',
            'password',
            );
        $adapter->setIdentity($loginForm->getValue('username'));
        $adapter->setCredential($loginForm->getValue('password'));

        $auth = Zend_Auth::getInstance();
        $result = $auth->authenticate($adapter);

        if ($result->isValid()) {
            $this->_helper->FlashMessenger('Successful Login');
            $this->redirect('/');
            return;
        } else {
            $this->_helper->FlashMessenger('Unsuccessful Login');
        }

    }
    $this->view->loginForm = $loginForm;        
}
```

Comment: Can you post some of the code where you create and display the form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling `isValid()` before displaying the form the first time, this is why you're getting the error. Probably the `$_POST` array is empty.

Try validating only for POST requests, i.e.:

```
if ($this->getRequest()->isPost()) {
    if($loginForm->isValid($_POST)) { 
       ...
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.